# What does "\$\cos(2t)u(t)\$" stand for in this context?

Tags: circuit-analysis, transfer-function

[image]

The question in the above diagram asks for "steady state current to \$\cos(2t)u(t)\$" of the network. I'm not sure what \$\cos(2t)u(t)\$ is, in this context. Is it the transfer function? Or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is a bit ambiguous, but the likely meaning is

"What is the system's port current in response to an applied voltage \$v(t)=\cos(2t)u(t)\$?".

The diagram tells you what the current is when the applied voltage is simply \$v(t)=u(t)\$. From this you can find the current for any other (finite-power) \$v(t)\$, and they're asking you about one such case.

If they really mean it about the "steady state" part, they're asking what is the final sinusoidal steady state response after all short term transients due to the input signal only being applied after \$t=0\$ settle out.

To answer the question in your title, "\$\cos(2t)u(t)\$" means a cosine signal with angular frequency 2 rad/s, multiplied by the unit step function.

Comment: Thanks, but how exactly to find the output for \$\cos(2t)u(t)\$, given I know the output for \$u(t)\$? It's not very clear to me...

Comment: This is probably what the taught you in the last 2 or 3 chapters of your book.

Comment: I'm afraid that's not a very helpful response. We aren't using any specific textbook.

Comment: Where did you get the problem from then? Look there. This site gives a few paragraph answers to single questions. There isn't enough space here to give a complete course in linear systems.

Comment: The problem is from a question paper. Anyhow, thanks. I'll try to figure it out myself.

Comment: There are 3 or 4 different ways to solve it. The one you're expected to use depends on what you're being taught.

Comment: Well, it seems that I need to first convert all the current and voltages to Laplace domain, and the transfer function would be  \$H(s)=\frac{I_{\text{output}}(s)}{V_{\text{input}}(s)}\$. Inverse Laplace transforming \$H(s)\$ should give me the current response for unit-impulse input voltage. Then I need to convolute the \$\cos(2t)u(t)\$ with the unit-impulse input voltage. Does that seem right?

Comment: One thing I'm not sure about is that whether the transfer function can be written as a ratio of output current and input voltage or whether it is only a ratio of currents. I don't know the impedance (directly), so is that a problem?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76372/discussion-between-user554252-and-the-photon).

Answer (score 2):

You're given the input current when a 1V step is  applied, hence you can find the differential equation defining the LTI system. From this you can determine the response to cos(2t)u(t), either by solving the differential equation or via the Laplace transform.

Alternatively, since initial conditions are clearly zero, determine the TF: \$\frac{I(s)}{V(s)}\$ by Laplace transforming \$\small i(t)\$, and noting that the Laplace transform of the input is \$\small V(s)=\large \frac{1}{s}\$.

\$ s \rightarrow j\omega\$ will then allow you to determine the steady state response to the given sinusoid.